# R devtools fails as "Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path"

Tags: xml, r, ubuntu, devtools, pkg-config

I am trying to install devtools in R version 3.2.1, however when I do the following error is thrown:

```
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing libxml-2.0.pc
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

when I run `dpkg -L libxml2-dev` in a terminal I find:

```
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/xml2-config
/usr/share
/usr/share/aclocal
/usr/share/aclocal/libxml2.m4
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/xml2-config.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man3
/usr/share/man/man3/libxml.3.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xml2Conf.sh
/usr/include
/usr/include/libxml2
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/globals.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/schematron.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xlink.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/HTMLparser.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/pattern.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlexports.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlschemas.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/list.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/entities.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlstring.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/hash.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/relaxng.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlsave.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/SAX2.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlIO.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlschemastypes.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xpathInternals.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/schemasInternals.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmodule.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/valid.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/c14n.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlwriter.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlunicode.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/nanohttp.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/catalog.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlerror.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/nanoftp.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlautomata.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xinclude.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/HTMLtree.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/chvalid.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parserInternals.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xpointer.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/dict.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlregexp.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/DOCBparser.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlreader.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/SAX.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/threads.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/debugXML.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xpath.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/uri.h
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/README
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/TODO.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so
```

to try and add this to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` I tried: `env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` however this does not seem to work.

Comment: You only get these two lines when your run `dpkg -L libxml2-dev`? If yes, `libxml2` is probably not installed.

Comment: @Pascal, No There are more I just added the two that seemed pertinent. I have added the full output from the call now for clarity.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

OK so in the end I had to manually install libxml2 even though my system said it allready had the most up to date version installed after: `sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev`

I manually installed based on info found [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libxml2.html):

```
wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz
```

Then uppack to a directory, e.g.:

```
tar -xvf libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz
cd libxml2-2.9.2
```

Configure the install:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static --with-history && make
```

and

```
sudo make install
```

after this the R command `install.packages("devtools")` completed with success.

Comment: Good to know.  There is either a Debian/Ubuntu bug here, and/or a bug with the xml2 package.  In either case you should really not change `/usr/local` to `/usr` as you now continue to mix local installations with package installations.  That is generally a bad idea ...

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 without doing anything after the `wget` step

Answer (score 12):

Choose and Install suitable library from below as per your Linux flavor:-

> - deb: **libxml2-dev** (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
> - rpm: **libxml2-devel** (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
> - csw: **libxml2_dev** (Solaris)

Install with an appropriate command like apt-get, yum, etc.

Comment: Please note you might still get an error due to `libxml2-dev` not being installed properly if you go the `apt-get, yum, etc.` way. What worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 was the command `wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz` as @mattbawn suggested above

Comment: Thank you, this fixed a `pip` issue for me. Much better than manually building from source.

Answer (score 6):

From within R prompt, this command works provided that `libxml2-dev` has been installed:

```
Sys.setenv(PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig")
```

Comment: My specific problem seemed to be an issue with my system not recognising the configuration of libxml2-dev but +1 for the tip!

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried this first before trying to install libxml2-dev manually, it helps

Answer (score 2):

For the narrower problem of installing the R package "XML", just do

```
 sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml
```

Otherwise, start at the list of dependencies for "devtools" (eg from [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/devtools/index.html)) and install these dependencies one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I'm missing something. If I do this and try again to install devtools the installation still fails with the same error. `* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable`. Can you clarity for me please?

Comment: Sorry, so it is package `xml2`, not package `XML` and the binary won't help you.  My recommendation of installation dependencies one by one and checking _their individual error logs_ still stands.  All those packages install just fine on all my Ubuntu machines ...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Fedora 31 (as of Apr 2020; error in `xml2` installation). Installing `libxml2-devel` seems to solve it for me.

`$ dnf install libxml2-devel`

Comment: Thanks, I was having issues installing tidyverse on MX Linux and this was one of the packages I was missing but the error message didn't mention libxml2-devel.

Answer (score 0):

Today, 4 years and 2 months later, I was having exactly the same issue (even if in the context of the installation of a different package, xml2).

Looking closely at the .configure script of the package, I noticed that following one-line configuration test was failing:

`echo "#include $PKG_TEST_HEADER" | ${CC} ${CPPFLAGS} ${PKG_CFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} -E -xc - >/dev/null 2>&1 || R_CONFIG_ERROR=1;`

This is despite all the used parameters having correct and non-null values.

I'm not sure why exactly this test fails, but it seems to be a bug (so Dirk Eddelbuettel was right). Commenting out the test, allowed me to manually install the package without any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

if you used conda env `R`, then use conda to resolve this problem.

`conda install -c anaconda libxml2`