# How to compile R with Cairo and XQuartz support in macOS?

Tags: r, installation, homebrew

I am trying to run a script that requires `xQuartz`. It runs just fine in Rstudio but when I call the script with `Rscript` , it fails and produces `Error in x11() : X11 is not available`.

When I run the following, I get this output.

```
> capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets      libxml 
      FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
       fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

If I am reading this correctly, it would seem that my `R` was not built with `X11` support.

To remedy this problem, I tried to reinstall R through `homebrew` with the command:

`brew reinstall R --with-java --with-openblas --with-x --with-cairo`

`homebrew` fails to recognizes `--with-x` and `--with-cairo` as options. However, in the proceeding configure text, `homebrew` explicitly states

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.0_1 --enable-memory-profiling --without-cairo --without-x
```

I tried `--without-x=no` and `--without-cairo=no` and both options were not recognized.

---

How would I make `X11` recognizable to `Rscript`? Is this the right way? If so, how would I install R with those capbailities?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason for installing R through `homebrew` instead of using the official macOS binaries from CRAN? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017001/r-nightmare-yosemite-r-rstudio-and-homebrew) seems highly relevant to your case.

Comment: Thank you for your post! I'll give installing R from the CRAN a try. I just used `homebrew` for ease of use.